# How to I can view background apps in a React Native application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

I'm working on a Gaming Social Media app with react native and I need to access information about background apps running on the device. Specifically, I want to retrieve a list of background apps along with their information such as the time when it started and package name. to set status automatically for ex: "playing {game name}" if user allow me.

I've searched through the React Native documentation and various libraries, but I couldn't find a clear solution for this. Is there a native module or library available that allows me to achieve this functionality? If not, what would be the recommended approach to implement this feature in a React Native application?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Impossible on iOS. It would be a huge privacy violation

Answer (score 0):

1.First, install the react-native-appstate-listener package,
2.Link the package (if not auto-linked),
3.Import the necessary modules in your React Native component,
4.Create a component and use the AppStateListener to listen for changes in the app state..

Comment: I appreciate your answer to my query. however, It is not useful for me.

Comment: sorry but,-it happens !